# Mat paginator not updating page index when clicked on next page button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, pagination

I have implemented a mat data table along with mat-paginator so what is happening that i want to fetch data from server when next page button is clicked on the paginator but when i click on the button it fetches the new data but the page index is not updated and it always stuck on page 1 despite of new data fetched
Refer following images:

1. Before clicking next page button:
   [image]

and when i click on button only the data in the mat table changes once and after that even i press next button data is not updated also see the disabled previous button

it looks like pageIndex of paginator is not properly being updated

The code structure is like the data-table-component is a child component inside the orders-page-component where the api calls are being made.

1. DataTableComponent.ts

```
export class DataTableComponent<T> implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  public _tableData: MatTableDataSource<T> = new MatTableDataSource();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) matSort!: MatSort;

  @Output() refreshDataSource = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() viewDetails = new EventEmitter<T>();
  @Output() deleteItem = new EventEmitter<T>();
  @Output() pageChangeEvent = new EventEmitter<T>();

  @Input() set tableData(data: T[]) {
    this._tableData = new MatTableDataSource<T>(data);
    this._tableData.paginator = this.paginator;
    this._tableData.sort = this.matSort;
  }

  @Input() set totalRecords(records:number) {
    this._totalRecords = records
  }
  public _totalRecords = 0
  @Input() sortByColumn:string = ''
  @Input() entityText:string = ''

  @Input() showAddToCartButton:boolean = false
  // @Input() goToViewDetailsFn: ((item: T) => void) | undefined;
  // @Input() openDeletePopUpForItemFn: ((item: T) => void) | undefined;

  @Input() page = 1
  @Input() COLUMNS_SCHEMA: ColumnSchema[] = [];
  @Input() tableColumns: string[] = this.COLUMNS_SCHEMA.map((col) => col.key);

  currentPage: number = 0;
  totalNumberOfPages: number = 0;
  showLoader: boolean = false;

  disableButtonForProducts: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private cartService: CartService
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getRangeDisplayText;
    this.paginator.length = this._totalRecords
    this.currentPage = this.paginator.pageIndex + 1;
    this.totalNumberOfPages = this.paginator.getNumberOfPages();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCartItems()
  }

  startLoader() {
    this.showLoader = true;
  }

  stopLoader() {
    this.showLoader = false;
  }

  filterChanged(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this._tableData.filter = filterValue;
  }

  goToViewDetails(item: T) {
    this.viewDetails.emit(item);
  }

  openDeletePopUpForItem(item: T) {
    this.deleteItem.emit(item);
  }

  onPageChange(event: any) {
    console.log({event});
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex + 1;
    console.log("Page Index:", this.paginator.pageIndex);
    
    this.pageChangeEvent.emit(event)
  }


  getCartItems() {
    this.cartService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
      //empty the current array to enable buttons which are removed from carts
      this.disableButtonForProducts = [];
      data.forEach((element: any) => {
        this.disableButtonForProducts.push(element.productGuid);
      });
    });
  }

  addToCart(product: any) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }

  getRangeDisplayText = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
    const initialText = `Displaying ${this.entityText}`; // Customize this line
    if (length == 0 || pageSize == 0) {
      return `${initialText} 0 of ${length}`;
    }
    length = Math.max(length, 0);
    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
    const endIndex =
      startIndex < length
        ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length)
        : startIndex + pageSize;
    return `${initialText} (${startIndex + 1} to ${endIndex}) of ${length}`; // Customize this line
  };
}
```

2. DataTableComponent.html

```
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-8">
                <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                [pageIndex]="page - 1"
                (page)="onPageChange($event)" showFirstLastButtons>
                </mat-paginator>

            </div>

<mat-table matSort [matSortActive]="sortByColumn"  matSortDirection="asc" [dataSource]="_tableData" [ngClass]="{'mat-table-header-row-if-loader' : showLoader}">
</mat-table>
```

3. OrdersPageComponent.ts

```
export class OrdersPageComponent implements OnInit {


  /*
    Note: Only Add columns in tableColumns if it is also present in displayNameForColumns
    Or else it will throw an error
  */

  tableColumns = ["orderId",
    "customerFullName",
    // "customerId",
    // "customerGuid",
    // "payments",
    "paymentStatus",
    // "remarks",
    "totalAmountWithGst",
    // "totalAmountWithGstAndDiscount",
    // "totalDiscount",
    // "totalLabour",
    "orderDate",
    "cancelledAt",
    "actions"]

displayNameForColumns: ColumnSchema[] =
  [
    {
      key: "orderId",
      type: "text",
      label: "Id"
    },
    {
      key: "customerFullName",
      type: "text",
      label: "Customer Name"
    },
    {
      key: "totalAmountWithGst",
      type: "text",
      label: "Bill Amount"
    },
    {
      key: "paymentStatus",
      type: "text",
      label: "Payment Status"
    },
    {
      key: "orderDate",
      type: "date",
      label: "Order Date"
    },
    {
      key: "cancelledAt",
      type: "date",
      label: "Cancelled On"
    },
    {
      key: "actions",
      type: "text",
      label: "Actions"
    },
  ]

  itemsPerPage = 5;
  totalRecords = 0
  currentPage = 1
  totalNumberOfPages = 0

  getAllOrdersSubscription = new Subscription
  ordersData:OrdersDataModel[] = []
  constructor(
    private ordersService: OrderService,
    private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
    private loaderService: NgxUiLoaderService,
    private loggerService: LoggerService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllOrders()
  }

  getAllOrders(itemsPerPage = this.itemsPerPage, pageNumber = 1) {
    this.loggerService.LogInfo("getAllOrders() Request Started.")

    this.loaderService.start()
    this.getAllOrdersSubscription = this.ordersService.getAllOrders(itemsPerPage, pageNumber).subscribe({
      next: (response)=> {
        console.log(response);
        this.currentPage = pageNumber
        this.totalRecords = response[0].totalRecords
        this.calculatePages()
        this.ordersData = this.prepareOrdersData(response.slice(1))
        this.loggerService.LogInfo("getAllOrders() Request Completed.")
        this.loaderService.stop()
      },
      error: (error)=> {
        this.loggerService.LogError(error, "getAllOrders()")
        this.loaderService.stop()
      }
    })
  }

  handlePageChange(event:any) {
    this.getAllOrders(event.pageSize, event.pageIndex + 1)
  }

  prepareOrdersData(orders:any):OrdersDataModel[] {
    const ordersData:OrdersDataModel[] = orders.map((order:any) => (
      {
        orderId: order.id,
        orderGuid: order.invoiceGuid,
        orderDate: order.createdAt,
        customerFullName: order.customer_details.firstName + ' ' + order.customer_details.lastName,
        customerId: order.customer_details.customerId,
        customerGuid: order.customer_details.customerGuid,
        payments: order.payments,
        paymentStatus: order.isPaymentDone === true? PaymentStatus.DONE : PaymentStatus.PENDING,
        remarks: order.remarks ?? null,
        totalAmountWithGst: this.decimalPipe.transform(order.totalAmountWithGst),
        totalAmountWithGstAndDiscount: order.totalAmountWithoutGstAndDiscount,
        totalDiscount: order.totalDiscount,
        totalGst: order.totalGst,
        totalLabour: order.totalLabour,
        cancelledAt: order.cancelledAt
      }
    ))

    return ordersData
  }

  calculatePages() {
    this.totalNumberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.itemsPerPage)
  }

  goToViewDetails(orderData: OrdersDataModel) {
    this.router.navigate([`orders/view-order-details/${orderData.orderGuid}`]); 
  }

  openDeletePopUpForItem(orderData: OrdersDataModel) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: `Are you sure you want to cancel this order?`,
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, cancel it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        this.loggerService.LogInfo("cancelOrder() Request Started.")
        this.ordersService.cancelOrder(orderData.orderGuid).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.getAllOrders()
            if (data.length == 0 || !data[0]?.message) {
              Swal.fire(
                'Cancelled!',
                "Order Cancelled Successfully.",
                'success'
              )
            this.loggerService.LogInfo("cancelOrder() Request Completed.")
            }
            else {
              this.loggerService.LogError(data[0].message ?? 'Failed to cancel order', "cancelOrder()")
              Swal.fire(
                'Error',
                data[0].message ?? 'Failed to cancel order',
                'error'
              )
            }
          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.loggerService.LogError(error, "cancelOrder()")
            Swal.fire(
              'Error!',
              error,
              'error'
            )
          }
        })


      }
    })
  }

}
```

4. OrdersPageComponent.html

```
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <app-data-table [COLUMNS_SCHEMA]="displayNameForColumns" [tableColumns]="tableColumns"
                            (viewDetails)="goToViewDetails($event)" (deleteItem)="openDeletePopUpForItem($event)"
                            [tableData]="ordersData" (refreshDataSource)="getAllOrders()"
                            [entityText]="'Orders'"
                            [sortByColumn]="'orderDate'"
                            [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
                            [page]="currentPage"
                            (pageChangeEvent)="handlePageChange($event)"
                            ></app-data-table>
                    </div>
```

I dont know why the paginator buttons are not updated when page is changed

Also i've noticed that for a moment the page index is changed from 0 to 1 but then again it is getting reset i guess due to the piece of code written in **ngAfterViewChecked()** in **DataTableComponent** but i am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example of your code so we can debug issue?